# Spark join performance optimization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to execute the below query using spark. How can I optimize the join.

Each data frame has records in millions

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT col1,
                col2,
                col3...
FROM ool
INNER JOIN ooh ON ool.header_key = ooh.header_key
              AND ool.org_key = ooh.org_key
INNER JOIN msib ON ool.inventory_item_key = msib.inventory_item_key
               AND ool.ship_from_org_key = msib.o_key
INNER JOIN curr ON curr.from_currency = ooh.transactional_curr_code
               AND date_format(curr.date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = date_format(ooh.date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
INNER JOIN mtl_parameters mp ON ool.ship_from_org_key = mp.o_key
INNER JOIN ood ON ood.o_key = mp.o_key
INNER JOIN ot ON ooh.order_type_key = ot.transaction_type_key
INNER JOIN csu ON ool.ship_to_org_key = csu.site_use_key
INNER JOIN csa ON csu.site_key = csa._site_key
INNER JOIN ps ON csa.party_key = ps.party_key
INNER JOIN hca ON csa.account_key = hca.account_key
INNER JOIN hp ON hca.party_key = hp.party_key
INNER JOIN hl ON ps.location_key = hl.location_key
INNER JOIN csu1 ON ool.invoice_to_key = csu1.use_key
INNER JOIN csa1 ON ool.invoice_to_key = csu1.use_key
               AND csu1.cust_acctkey = csa1.custkey
INNER JOIN ps1 ON csa1.party_key = ps1.party_key
INNER JOIN hca1 ON csa1.cust_key = hca1.cust_key
INNER JOIN hp1 ON hca1.party_key = hp1.party_key
INNER JOIN hl1 ON ps1.loc_key = hl1.loc_key
INNER JOIN hou ON ool.or_key = hou.o_key
```

How can I optimize this join in pyspark?

ooh and ool are the driver dataframes and their record count will be in hundreds of million range.

Comment: I do not think there is much you can do. You query is pretty neat, you have equi-joins, it seems ok. The only thing you could do is using bucket maybe but I am not even sure that would improve things. The other thing you can try is to change the table order in the query, you put first the small tables and join the biggest at the end. It will reduce the suffle time on each join.

Comment: Thanks, will keep that in mind!